# Class not Registered exception in java

Tags: java, c#, web-services, soap, soap-client

I am consuming a SOAP webservice in JAVA. I have created stubs. When I Execute the code I am getting

```
    Server was unable to process request. ---> 
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {28487481-0A2C-4E61-A198-417335F22895} 
failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

After googling a bit, I found out this is relevant to C#. But I am using JAVA. Not sure Why am I seeing this. Would be helpful, If you can throw some light on this.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with C# aside from the fact that the same error can occur in C# if using a COM class that isn't registered. The answer is, register the class.

Comment: Thanks a lot @itsme86, Can you help me register the same not sure which class it is referring to

Comment: Well, which COM classes are you using in your application? You could dig through the registry and find out what it is by the GUID. Once you figure it out, use [regsrv32](https://www.poftut.com/register-and-unregister-windows-dll-files-with-regsrv32-command/) to register it.

Comment: Thanks @itsme86 again, SO I am using a java client to consume the webservice that is hosted in a different server. SHould I have to register the class from the server or is it the SOAPclient ?